# merge pdf despatches onto template with terms and conditions on back and print from a batch job

Tags: pdf, batch, merge, templates

I need to print hundreds of despatch notes.

Need to create a despatch note template with terms and conditions printed on the back of the page,  then pick up the raw data pdfs and merge onto template.  I also need to be able to call this from a batch job.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: This question might be better asked on [softwarerecs.se]. You should check out their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/), specifically [On-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Off-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [How to Ask a Good Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), before posting a question there.

Comment: **Close voters**: this is easily phrased as a *how do I do X* question, please take that into consideration when reviewing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I used Sejda-console for this kind of task combined with VBA in an excel enviroment. Works like a charm, i use it to bind technical documentation to a excel template.